# Extract coordinates out of list() in R

Tags: r, coordinates, extents, list

I have a data.frame with a column called geo. In this column, there are lists with coordinates that used to represent bounding boxes. I would like to grab the coordinates that are inside each list and create two points.

dput:

```
structure(list(full_name = c("Karlsruhe, Deutschland", "Volksparkstadion", 
"Hamburg, Deutschland"), country_code = c("DE", "DE", "DE"), 
    place_type = c("city", "poi", "city"), name = c("Karlsruhe", 
    "Volksparkstadion", "Hamburg"), country = c("Deutschland", 
    "Deutschland", "Deutschland"), id = c("5b146bf0b819f1af", 
    "0fc3a3fa5494c000", "5bcd72da50f0ee77"), geo = list(bbox = list(
        8.2773, 48.9405, 8.5418, 49.0914), bbox = list(9.8986, 
        53.5871, 9.8986, 53.5871), bbox = list(8.4202, 53.3951, 
        10.3252, 53.9647))), row.names = c(2L, 5L, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

The column is a list of lists of length 4. So for example you can extract the four coordinates as a vector this way:

```
> unlist(x$geo[[1]])
[1]  8.2773 48.9405  8.5418 49.0914
> unlist(x$geo[[2]])
[1]  9.8986 53.5871  9.8986 53.5871
```

Applying `unlist` over the column will return a list of length-4 vectors:

```
> Map(unlist, x$geo)
$bbox
[1]  8.2773 48.9405  8.5418 49.0914

$bbox
[1]  9.8986 53.5871  9.8986 53.5871

$bbox
[1]  8.4202 53.3951 10.3252 53.9647
```

You've not said quite clearly how you want to create these two points. But for example another `Map` over those vectors can do something like make a point out of the first two numbers using the `st_point` function from the `sf` package:

```
> Map(function(p){st_point(p[1:2])}, Map(unlist, x$geo))
$bbox
POINT (8.2773 48.9405)

$bbox
POINT (9.8986 53.5871)

$bbox
POINT (8.4202 53.3951)
```

Or you could stick an `sfc` call in there and make a list of spatial points vectors with two points in each:

```
> Map(function(p){st_sfc(st_point(p[1:2]), st_point(p[3:4]))}, Map(unlist, x$geo))
$bbox
Geometry set for 2 features 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 8.2773 ymin: 48.9405 xmax: 8.5418 ymax: 49.0914
CRS:           NA
POINT (8.2773 48.9405)
POINT (8.5418 49.0914)
```

Comment: Hello @spacedman, thank you for your kind response. I would like to create a point that lies in the middle of the bbox. Is this also possible?

Comment: You should maybe ask this as a new question, and be clear about the format of the output you want - a matrix with x and y columns, some sf_point objects, etc etc.

Comment: perfect, I will ask a new question